# Recreating a sentence using text files and lists

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python and I am currently working on a compression program that uses lists containing positions of words in a lists and a list of words that make up the sentence. So far I have written my program inside two functions, the first function; 'compression', gets the words that make up the sentence and the positions of those words. My second function is called 'recreate', this function uses he lists to recreate the sentence. The recreated senetence is then stored in a file called recreate.txt. My issue is that the positions of words and the words that make up the sentence are not being written to their respective files and the 'recreate' file is not being created and written to. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

```
sentence = input("Input the sentence that you wish to be compressed") 
sentence.lower()
sentencelist = sentence.split() 
d = {} 
plist = [] 

wds = []
def compress():     
    for i in sentencelist:
        if i not in wds:
            wds.append(i)
    for i ,j in enumerate(sentencelist):
        if j in (d):  
            plist.append(d[j]) 
        else:
            plist.append(i)      
    print (plist) 

    tsk3pos = open ("tsk3pos.txt", "wt")    

    for item in plist:
        tsk3pos.write("%s\n" % item)    

    tsk3pos.close()                     
    tsk3wds = open ("tsk3wds.txt", "wt")    

    for item in wds:
        tsk3wds.write("%s\n" % item)    
    tsk3wds.close() 

    print (wds) 

def recreate(compress): 
    compress()
    num = list()
    wds = list()
    with open("tsk3wds.txt", "r") as txt: 
        for line in txt:
            words += line.split()

    with open("tsk3pos.txt", "r") as txt:
        for line in txt:
            num += [int(i) for i in line.split()]



    recreate = ' '.join(words[pos] for pos in num)

    with open("recreate.txt", "wt") as txt:
        txt.write(recreate)
```

---

UPDATED 
I have fixed all other problems except the recreate function which will not make the 'recreate' file and will not recreate the sentence with the words, although 
it recreates the sentence with the positions.

```
def recreate(compress): #function that will be used to recreate the compressed sentence.
    compress()
    num = list()
    wds = list()

    with open("words.txt", "r") as txt: #with statement opening the word text file
        for line in txt: #iterating over each line in the text file.
            words += line.split() #turning the textfile into a list and appending it to num

    with open("tsk3pos.txt", "r") as txt:
        for line in txt:
            num += [int(i) for i in line.split()]

    recreate = ' '.join(wds[pos] for pos in num)

    with open("recreate.txt", "wt") as txt:
        txt.write(recreate) 

    main()



def main():
    print("Do you want to compress an input or recreate a compressed input?")
    user = input("Type 'a' if you want to compress an input. Type 'b' if you wan to recreate an input").lower()
    if user not in ("a","b"):
        print ("That's not an option. Please try again")
    elif user == "a":
        compress()
    elif user == "b":
        recreate(compress)
    main()

main()
```

Comment: First off, don't use `variable = open(file)`, use the `with` context manager. You seem to be switching back and forth...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've changed all variable = open(file) to the 'with' context manager and I have checked my code and I still can't pick out any problems. @MattDMo

Comment: What does "Enter code here" mean? Is there any other code you're not showing? Because currently you're defining the functions but never calling them.

Comment: Also, your `sentence.lower()` is not being assigned to anything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Enter code wasn't supposed to be put in there @user234461

Comment: @Goodies The sentence.lower() is used to convert the user's input to lower case

Comment: I know what `.lower()` does. I'm saying it is not being assigned to anything. It's like putting `i = 5; i + 1;` in your code. `i` would not be `6`.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler ( yet less efficient ) approach :

```
 recreate_file_object  =  open ( "C:/FullPathToWriteFolder/recreate.txt"   ,   "w"   )
 recreate_file_object.write ( recreate ) 
 recreate_file_object.close ( )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should that resolve the issue of the recreate file not being created? @RasikhJ

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll give it a go @RasikhJ